# WebStorm says console is an unresolved variable

Tags: webstorm

For some reason WebStorm says that the global `console` variable in javascript is unresolved. How can I resolve this?

I am using Node.js

[image]

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7400 , try 7.0 EAP.

Comment: Well, 7 has a limited time trail. I'd like to stick with 6.0 because I have a license for it.

Comment: It's limited for 30 days after the build date, no problem as new builds come more often than once per month, so you can use it until 7.0 is released.

Comment: @gustavohenke: Here is the problem, that console is the console under the DHTML.js library. I want the console under console.js library. So his answer is wrong actually. Its not the console node.js provides.

Comment: I know this is a long time after your OP but I got this to stop warning on `console` in PHPStorm 10 via Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Code Quality Tools > JSHint > Select Node.js under Environments and hit Apply

Answer (score 44, accepted):

the solution for WebStorm 6.* is to enable 'HTML' library in Settings/javascript/Libraries
(same for WebStorm 7.0.1)

Comment: This worked for me as well. But JetBrains *should* make this work with Node globals selected as well. It's not really HTML, but a both a browser and Node global...

Comment: Works on PyCharm too. Probably in all jetBrains IDEs as well

Answer (score 20):

For version 8 and up the solution is to enable `NodeJS Globals`library:

`Settings > Javascript > Libraries`

Comment: This works, but why is it necessary and what does it do?

Comment: It works because 'console' is not part of the javascript language.  It's just a global variable that's available in most (but not all) javascript containers.

Answer (score 15):

Solution for webstorm for NodeJS as of January 2017

`Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Download -> TypeScript Community Stubs -> node -> Download and Install`

This will remove the unresolved import console warning

Comment: Node is not visible on the list

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problems. @CodeWhisperer I found it just fine. Just let it load.

Answer (score 3):

For me worked to change Javascript Language Version to **ECMAScript 6** in

```
File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript
```

PhpStorm v.2017.2

Comment: Switching to `ECMAScript 5.1` and back to `ECMAScript 6+` did the trick for me on `Webstorm 2020.1`.

Answer (score 2):

For my Version (WebStorm 2021.3) it was under `Languages & Framework => Node.js` and then check `Coding assistance for Node.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to resolve this by deleting the Webstorm preferences folder and re-installing Webstorm.