# Webstorm 7 cannot recognize node API methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I just installed WebStorm. I'm working on a small Node.js app.

I've attached the Node.js source code, and when I click on the Node.js settings, I can see that it can recognize my various node modules, etc.

I'm having two issues:

1. *Unresolved variable or type*: WebStorm doesn't seem to recognize simple API methods (`exports`, `require`).
2. *No code insight for…*: If I call `require('winston')`, it tells me that it has no code insight. (Is there a way I can add the source code?)

Comment: Can you check if Settings > JavaScript > Libraries > Node.js * are all checked?

Comment: @gustavohenke - Thank you that solved the first issue.  Is there a way I can help it with code insight?

Comment: I have the same issues in Windows but not a linux install of Webstorm. Looks very ugly to have all the red underlines.

Comment: @gustavohenke's suggestion worked for me, thanks for that.  In the most recent version (13.1.5) the "Node.js vx.xx.xx Core Modules" items were already checked, but not "Node.js Globals".  Checking that did the trick.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For WebStorm 7 thru 10 (on OSX)…

WebStorm → Preferences → Languages & Frameworks → Javascript → Libraries

Select "Node.js Globals" and "Node.js vXXX Core Modules".

Comment: Works for WebStorm 10.0.1 (on Windows 7) as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. WebStorm 10.0.3(Mac). Many Thanks.

Comment: Hey Ted, can you have a look at the comment under my answer? Thanks.

Comment: @DanDascalescu What am I looking for Dan?

Comment: file -> default settings -> languages & frameworks -> nodejs and npm -> coding assistance -> Enable

Comment: For me, now, the library required was simply "node" in the same spot that @TedBigham mentioned.

Answer (score 59):

For 2018 and later versions of WebStorm:

In <kbd>Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM</kbd>, check <kbd>Coding assistance for Node.js</kbd>:

[image: WebStorm setting to enable Coding assistance for Node.js]

<sub>In older Webstorm versions, this was called <kbd>Enable Node.js Core library</kbd>.</sub>

If you still see unrecognized Node symbols even with that option enabled, unckeck it, restart WebStorm, then right click on the warning and choose <kbd>Enable Node.js coding assistance</kbd> or just check the option again. Watch for WebStorm to show it's <kbd>Indexing</kbd> files. (Just had this happen today - looks like a WebStorm bug, and what I just wrote fixed the situation.)

Comment: The question is actually about WebStorm 7.  None of the answers claim to cover that, although after some googling I believe the accepted answer (mine) works with WS7 too.

Comment: @DanDascalescu The question was about WebStorm 7

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered on the [WebStorm says console is an unresolved variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257450/webstorm-says-console-is-an-unresolved-variable/55542475#55542475) question, to solve these problems on the new Webstorm versions, you need to enable the **Coding assistance for Node.js**.

To do this, go on the `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Node.js and NPM` and click on the `Coding assistance for Node.js` option, and then click **OK** to save:

[image]

This will all Node.js unresolved variables and functions.

#### Update

On the new Webstorm versions, just going above error and clicking in `More Actions...` (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and selecting
**Enable Node.js coding assistance** will solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use WebStorm 2020 and I had everything enabled but WebStill though showed that `module.exports` is unknown function. Then I turned off NodeJS.core library and NodeJS code assistance, applied and then turned them on again. And suddenly it started to work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working with WebStorm and Node.js these two code-segments regularly gave me "false positive" warnings:

FALSE POSITIVE WARNING CASE  1:

```
  module.exports =  ...
```

That gave me the warning "**Element is not exported**". I was able to get rid of the warning caused by that by putting this above the "module.exports = ..."

```
 /** @namespace module.exports **/
```

FALSE POSITIVE WARNING CASE  2:

```
 let something = global.something ;
```

That gave me the warning "**Unresolved variable or type global**". I was able to eliminate the warning caused by that by putting this above it:

```
 /** @namespace global **/
```

I now put the following on top of my .js- or .mjs-files to be executed by Node.js, and get rid of warnings referring to these variables or properties:

```
 /** @namespace global         **/
 /** @namespace console        **/
 /** @namespace process        **/
 /** @namespace Buffer         **/

 /** @namespace process.stdin  **/
 /** @namespace module.exports **/
```

I am using WebStorm 2022.2.3

Answer (score -1):

Updating to Webstorm 8 or higher will fix your require methods problem.  As posted earlier by checking if Settings > JavaScript > Libraries > Node.js are all checked will fix your problem