# PhpStorm: Unresolved variable or type console

Tags: javascript, ide, undefined, phpstorm

PhpStorm 9.0 states that `console`is undefined.

I have read and tried the answer for WebStorm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18273218/4620080 but that did not solve the problem. In Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries I have enabled the following: angular, HTML and HTML5/ECMAScript 5

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know the answer to this one as well. Frustrating that I'm getting error notices in PHPStorm for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, wherein I enabled the angular library, but kept getting `unresolved variable or type angular`

You can wipe the plugin cache to rebuild it. Its possible phpstorm has cached your setup of not having HTML enabled. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206850535-Fix-for-13-1-AngularJS-plugin-not-working-possibly-other-plugins-too-