# Why is unresolved JavaScript variable "Weak Warning" instead of "Error" in WebStorm Inspection?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Why not just think unresolved JavaScript variable an error?

I am from Java and cannot figure out that. Is it because JavaScript have some unresolved JavaScript variable that even IDE cannot know?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario: webstorm cannot predict what variables will be available globally. For example check jQuery's $ sign.

A related question: [Webstorm says console is an unresolved variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257450/webstorm-says-console-is-an-unresolved-variable?rq=1)

Comment: Other reasons: variable is only known in runtime, because it is a property of json received through ajax call, for example; or, property is constructed dynamically while executing the program can thus can't be resolved during static analysis. This is a consequence of JavaScript dynamic nature: as we can't tell for sure if this unresolved variable a user error that needs to be fixed, we show it as a warning rather than error